# How to compare two dataframes in Python pandas and output the difference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df with the same numbers of columns but different numbers of rows.

df1

```
   col1  col2
0     a    1,2,3,4
1     b    1,2,3
2     c    1
```

df2

```
   col1  col2
0     b    1,3
1     c    1,2
2     d    1,2,3
3     e    1,2
```

df1 is the existing list, df2 is the updated list. The expected result is whatever in df2 that was previously not in df1.

Expected result:

```
   col1  col2
0     c    2
1     d    1,2,3
2     e    1,2
```

I've tried with

```
mask = df1['col2'] != df2['col2']
```

but it doesn't work with different rows of df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) by splitted values in columns `col2`, then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `right join` and indicato parameter, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only rows with `right_only` and last aggregate `join`:

```
df11 = df1.assign(col2 = df1['col2'].str.split(',')).explode('col2')
df22 = df2.assign(col2 = df2['col2'].str.split(',')).explode('col2')

df = df11.merge(df22, indicator=True, how='right', on=['col1','col2'])

df = (df[df['_merge'].eq('right_only')]
              .groupby('col1')['col2']
              .agg(','.join)
              .reset_index(name='col2'))
print (df)
  col1   col2
0    c      2
1    d  1,2,3
2    e    1,2
```

Comment: I got this error after trying with another set of data. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @GohKokHan - Is possible there is missing values? e.g. instead `1,2,3` is `NaN` ?

Comment: @GohKokHan - If yes, then should working change `df[df['_merge'].eq('right_only')]` to `df[df['_merge'].eq('right_only')].dropna(subset=['col2'])`